# jQuery / JavaScript is not executed all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the content after image_1 and image_2 are completely loaded. But, it is not working as expected

```
var loading = 0;

(function() {
  $(".image_1").on('load', function() {
    console.log('loading image_1');
    loading++;
    checkLoading();
  });

  $(".image_2").on('load', function() {
    console.log('loading image_2');
    loading++;
    checkLoading();
  });
})();

function checkLoading() {
  console.log('inside Loading check');
  if (loading == 2) {
    console.log('loading done' + loading);
    $('#loader-wrapper').fadeOut('fast').remove();
  }
}
```

This function is not working all the time. It is added in the footer of php file.

Sometimes, it removes the #loader-wrapper successfully. But few other times, #loader-wrapper is not removed from DOM and I don't see any console.log info on that time.

Comment: Maybe your self executing functions gets called before the images are on the page or the reverse, the images are already loaded, so the onload won't fire.

Comment: How is the image getting loaded ...is it making an HTTP request ...?? If yes then use promise

Comment: Images are just loaded in the img tag

Comment: @Mouser you are right. They must be loaded before the script starts to check. If found this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980962/jquery-check-if-image-already-loaded-before-binding-a-load-event

Comment: You can check if the image is already loaded using e.g.  `naturalWidth` as described here [Check if an image is loaded (no errors) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871), and if it is not loaded listen for the load event.

Comment: how about the complete property?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've placed the script at the footer (end of document), my best guess is that the images are already loaded before the script is initiated. Hence, I dont think the `.on("load", function(){` will ever be fired, as the load event simply doesn't happen after the script is initiated (it already has).

I've made a little demo fiddle here, as they (jsfiddle) also load the script after the images: [this is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z139f3dp/3/)

Try calling your function earlier (before) the images and see if this doesn't fix your issue.